# Amazon AWS Ec2 + Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud-hosting

I'm trying to set up an EC2 instance with a public domain name that I bought from 123-reg.

Aside from associating the elastic IP with the instance that's running, and changing the DNS at 123-reg, is there anything else I need to do to access the site?

Any ideas or tutorial links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set an A record on your DNS entry for the domain to point at the Elastic IP, that's it.